# Why do cable cars (gondola lifts) only have doors on one side?

Tags: gondolas-and-cable-cars

I have never seen a gondola lift (one with enclosed cabins with doors) that has doors on the side facing the cable going in the other direction. They always seem to have doors only on the side facing away from the other direction, never on both sides or always facing the middle. I wonder why this is, as this means it is impossible to have island platforms, which could be useful in saving space in some places.

Comment: because it is usually not needed, and it adds more moving part, and increase the risk of breakdown. anyway not related to travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to travel.

Comment: I know many cases of cable cars with doors on both sides and island platforms.

Comment: Right, there are any number of doors on both sides.

Answer (score 7):

The cable cars used on Grouse Mountain, BC, has doors on both sides.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Willeke why? It shows no explanation is necessary since the configuration does exist.